# How do I obtain the additional soldier customisation options in XCOM: Enemy Within?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I have noticed some videos on YouTube showing the soldier customisation screen with more options (e.g different suit/colours/helmet).

Is this a cheat or just an additional DLC pack I don't know about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The extra customization options were originally a pre-order bonus for XCOM Enemy Unknown.  They are now available via the [Elite Soldier DLC pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209811/).

Despite the price, this DLC is very important to obtain so that all of your soldiers can have the original X-COM "Guile" style hair.

Comment: I seriously do think it's an important feature, so you can color-code your soldiers by class.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - No, it's important so you can colour-code your soldiers to [look like the ponies](http://i.imgur.com/NvqgG.jpg).  :P  (But, yes I do agree with you - being able to tell your soldiers apart at a glance is great.)